# Using Quartz to schedule a Job

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I am just starting to learn Quartz scheduling and in the first step of it I am facing problems.
I am looking at the examples of it on its main website but when I am trying to develop it in my workspace it is giving me errors.

```
package testing.quartz.scheduler;

    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;

    import org.quartz.JobDetail;
    import org.quartz.Scheduler;
    import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
    import org.quartz.Trigger;
    import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

    public class TesterMain {

        /**
         * @param args
         */
         public void run() throws Exception {


                // First we must get a reference to a scheduler
                SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
                Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();


                // computer a time that is on the next round minute
                Date runTime = evenMinuteDate(new Date());<--Here its giving me error


                // define the job and tie it to our HelloJob class
                JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class)<--Here its giving me error
                    .withIdentity("job1", "group1")
                    .build();

                // Trigger the job to run on the next round minute
                Trigger trigger = newTrigger()<--Here its giving me error
                    .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
                    .startAt(runTime)
                    .build();

                // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
                sched.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

                // Start up the scheduler (nothing can actually run until the 
                // scheduler has been started)
                sched.start();


                // wait long enough so that the scheduler as an opportunity to 
                // run the job!
                try {
                    // wait 65 seconds to show job
                    Thread.sleep(65L * 1000L); 
                    // executing...
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

                // shut down the scheduler
                sched.shutdown(true);
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

               TesterMain example = new TesterMain();
                example.run();

            }

    }
```

I have specified places where its giving me compilation error. Telling these method is not there in your class. 
So I am wondering are these methods really valid (newTrigger, newJob, evenMinuteDate). 
I am totally confused. I have added all the jars which is required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't compile, because you forgot to import the right classes.
This probably fixes it:

```
import static org.quartz.DateBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import static org.quartz.SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;
import static org.quartz.DateBuilder.evenMinuteDate;
```

Import these classes to your class.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date runTime = evenMinuteDate(new Date());
```

The `evenMinuteDate` method is not declared anywhere.

```
JobDetail job = newJob(HelloJob.class);
```

The HelloJob class is not imported and missing a space between `new` and `Job`

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
```

You're missing a space between `new` and `Trigger()`

Comment: There should not be a space. If you add 'import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;' it will compile